# Boy who is also a prankster gets body swapped with his school principal

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

The story contains a boy, who loves to prank people and in general, just not follow the rules. The former principal, who was much more lenient retires and a new, stricter principal joins whom everyone hates. The boy finds something (a box or so) with his friends which (I think) he puts near or in the principal's drawer, and by the use of that box, gets body swapped with the principal.

I think it ends with both of them having a different look on their approaches to life..

The author has written more such books, and this one has a bright orange cover. It had some illustration in black and white and had quite a lot of pages (somewhere around 300-400 if not lesser).  I found this book a while back and forgot about it again.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this? And was it new at the time, or older?

Comment: @LogicDictates Read it like 5-7 years back, it had been published for 3-4 years if I am not wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Head Kid](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40651376) by David Baddiel. It was published in 2018, so within your timeframe. The boy is a prankster, the old head teacher retires, and he body swaps with the new one.

From Goodreads:

> Bracket Wood is about to be visited by the school inspectors. But there's one big Ryan Ward. The maestro of practical jokes, Ryan has played so many tricks that in the end the Head Teacher just walks out. And then the new Head Teacher, Mr Carter, arrives. A man so strict even the teachers are scared of him. So imagine his surprise and Ryans when they swap bodies. Now Ryan is Head Teacher and his mortal enemy is one of his pupils. Its every naughty kids dream! But soon Bracket Wood School is in a total mess and only its worst ever pupil can fix it

The cover is bright orange:

[image]

Comment: YES, this is it!! Thanks for the help; my bad I got the publishing timeframe wrong though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Incidentally, the author of this book, [David Baddiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Baddiel), was formerly a stand-up comedian, and back in the '90s and early 2000s, was better known for being a comedian than an author, making regular appearances on UK television.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I knew he was a comedian, and only found out today he's a writer as well. Had a double take when I saw the name! Really enjoyed him in season 9 of _Taskmaster_.

Comment: @fez - I remember him more from older shows like _The Mary Whitehouse Experience_ and _Baddiel and Skinner Unplanned_. Not to mention the [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJqimlFcJsM) he and Frank Skinner recorded for the 1996 European Football Championship.

Comment: @LogicDictates wow I can barely recognise Frank Skinner!

Comment: @fez - [To paraphrase William Shatner](https://youtu.be/9V_LR89RwT4?t=156): _"Thirty years makes a difference."_

Comment: @LogicDictates Damn, didn't know Baddiel had such a history, explains why I really loved the humour in Head Kid now. Those shows are on my watchlist now!